# Cannot Build build.xml file in wso2 esb home/bin directory

Tags: ant, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

In WSO2 Documentation, they have said Open a command prompt (or a shell in Linux) and go to the `<ESB_HOME>\bin` directory. Then run the `ant` command as shown below to build the `build.xml` file.

In My Case If I run ant Command it shows command not found even though I run cmd in `bin` of `wso2`.
So Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install 'ant' first when you are using Windows. 
https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html